# ¿Cómo retornar valores de una consulta en una vista?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Desde mi controller tengo estas consultas

```
public function cargarDetalle($request)
{

        $articulo = vcomp_productos_web1::where('marca','=','forte')
        ->where('venta_web','=','SI')
        ->where('id','=',$request)
        ->first();

            return view('template2.productos.detalle', ['product' => $articulo]);
}
```

¿Cómo debería retornar la consulta en mi vista? estoy haciéndolo con un foreach

```
@section('detalle')

@foreach ($product as $product)
            <span>
                <span>{{ $product->descripcion }}</span>
                <p><b>Referencia: </b>{{ $product->referencia }}</p>
                <p><b>Empaque por: </b>{{ $product->unidad }}</p>
                <p>{{ $product->caracteristicas }}</p>
            </span>
@endforeach

@endsection
```

Comment: Por que devolviste la edición a tu pregunta, debes mostrar correctamente los bloques de código para mayor entendimiento de las personas que te puedan ayudar!

Comment: ¿`foreach ($product as $product)` ?

Comment: Ok, ya la edité y ya se ve bien, ahora no es necesario que utilices un foreach en la vista puesto que en el controlador estas usando ->first();, prueba a hacer esto en tu vista $product->descripcion sin utilizar foreach

Comment: ¿qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Listo @CamiloVasquez ponlo como respuesta! GRACIAS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu controlador estas usando `first()` y no `get()` por lo cual solo te va a llegar un **objeto** y no un **array de objetos**, es por esta razón que en tu vista no necesitas un `foreach` simplemente no hay **array** que recorrer, basta con que accedas a las propiedades de tu único **objeto** la siguiente manera:

```
<span>
   <span>{{ $product->descripcion }}</span>
   <p><b>Referencia: </b>{{ $product->referencia }}</p>
   <p><b>Empaque por: </b>{{ $product->unidad }}</p>
   <p>{{ $product->caracteristicas }}</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta respuesta es más una reescritura del código para mejorar las prácticas según como funciona Laravel:

```
public function cargarDetalle($id)
{
    $product = vcomp_productos_web1::where('marca', 'forte')
        ->where('venta_web', 'SI')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->first();

    return view('template2.productos.detalle', compact('product'));
}
```

En este método es más semántico definir el parámetro de entrada como `$id` en vez de `$request`, que en Laravel significa la "petición HTTP" entera y generalmente viene como inyección de dependencias `Request $request`. Por otra parte no es necesario agregar el `=` en las consultas where. Finalmente tampoco veo necesario redefinir una variable de nombre para terminar usando el nombre inicial, por lo cual `$product` está bien en todo el proceso.

```
@section('detalle')

        <span>
            <span>{{ $product->descripcion }}</span>
            <p><b>Referencia: </b>{{ $product->referencia }}</p>
            <p><b>Empaque por: </b>{{ $product->unidad }}</p>
            <p>{{ $product->caracteristicas }}</p>
        </span>

@endsection
```

En la vista realmente no hay ninguna modificación por hacer aparte de lo que explicó Camilo en su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

can you used: compact, but if you want retrieve a array:
eg. $array = [
  'users' => $usersArray,
  'products' => $productsArray
];

easy, 
return view('template2.productos.detalle', $array);

Comment: Hola Juan. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Por favor, pon la respueta en español. Y usa `ctr+k` para formatear el codigo.  Un saludo